# Mvc autocomplete ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Try to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#cityName').autocomplete({
            source: function(request,response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '@Url.Action("Search", "City")',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { name: request.term } ,
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                            alert(JSON.stringify(item.name));
                            return {
                                name: item.name, 
                                label: item.name
                            }
                        }));
                    }
                })
            },
            messages: {
                noResults: "", results: ""
            }
        })
    })
```

In `alert(JSON.stringify(data))` got this: {"items":["Boston","Berlin"]}.
In `alert(JSON.stringify(item.name))` got this: undefined.

Question: how do it (item.name) works?

Comment: Try `items[0]` - data it's object

Comment: It's works, but for only first name.

Comment: You have to use each loop, to go throught all elements

Comment: Yes, but what kind of output do you need from your ajax call, if it can be an array of string, you can just return `item`

Comment: @Sousuke it's a list of string, but if i try to return `item` i got 'Boston, Berlin' in same row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to just return array of strings:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#cityName').autocomplete({
            source: function(request,response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '@Url.Action("Search", "City")',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { name: request.term } ,
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data.items);
                    }
                })
            },
            messages: {
                noResults: "", results: ""
            }
        })
    })
```

Comment: I got it! Thanks you very much.